# What kind of bug is this?

Tags: pest-control

I apologize for the poor photos but if anyone can figure out what type of bug this is that would be a great help! I was sweeping the other night and when I looked down at my pile I realized some specks were moving!  Upon closer inspection, they were a bunch of tiny bugs! I would say as small as if you were to dot an i.  There were about 30 of them. Tonight, after sweeping some more in an additional area (I removed the children's playmat) we found some more!

Everyone is bite free. Though my son has had bites on his face and legs recently but we think they're mosquito bites (since we found one or two around the apartment).

Extra Info:
They are not located near the bedrooms or bed. I live in a second floor apartment in NYC. I feel like they might mostly resemble fleas - they're not as wide across as a bed beg.

[image: Bug trapped for reference]
[image: bug in motion]

Comment: They look like [bed bugs](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1725&bih=873&q=bed+bug).

Comment: @Comintern, doesn't look like a bed bug.  One, too large.  Body is too oval and the legs are positioned wrong.  On a bed bug, the legs are positioned closer to the head.

Comment: One second look, wrong about size as I didn't realize at that is a sheet of paper.  was looking at second picture only.  But take a look at pictures of bed bugs online and you will see it is not one.

Answer (score 1):

The closest match I could find is the Toe-winged Beetle. 2-16 mm in size. Large antennae, mainly a tropical, outdoor beetle. Your example looks to be about 2 mm.

http://bugguide.net/node/view/13057

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a carpet beetle. They look similar to bed bugs. My mom had a scare from them in her Brooklyn house. Take the sample to an exterminator to look at. You want to be sure it's not bed bugs.